# Private member (QByteArray) content is strange?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is the class:

```
class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ...
        void setCurrentFrame(const QPixmap &frame, const QByteArray &data);
        ...
    protected:
        // mouse events
        ...
    private:
        QPixmap currentFrame;
        QByteArray currentFrameData;
        ...
}
```

`setCurrentFrame` updates a frame and saves the last frame and byte array into private members:

```
void GraphicsScene::setCurrentFrame(const QPixmap &frame, const QByteArray &frameData)
{
    clear();
    addPixmap(frame);

    currentFrame = frame;
    currentFrameData = QByteArray(frameData);
    qDebug() << currentFrameData.toHex();   // this line works as expected
}
```

In the above code, `qDebug()` line prints byte array as expected. Now, look at this code:

```
void GraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    qDebug() << "GraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(): frame" << currentFrameData.size();      // works! size is printed
    for (int i = 0; i < currentFrameData.size(); ++i)
        qDebug() << currentFrameData.toHex().at(i);    // works! each character is printed

    qDebug() << currentFrameData.toHex();    // does not work! no content of currentFrameData 
    ...
    emit clicked(mouseEvent.pos(), currentFrameData);  // I need this signal to send me currentFrameData
    ...
}
```

I cannot get `currentFrameData` content. I need to use `currentFrameData` in other class's slot but it does not show anything even in this `GraphicsScene` class itself. I did not even know what to write in the question title. What is the problem here?

Comment: Every time you call the setCurrentFrame() function or before what event do you do it?

Comment: @eyllanesc, What do you mean by 'event'?

Comment: do you it every 10 seconds?, do you it every second?, what does it depend on you to call setCurrentFrame()?

Comment: Do you not modify the `currentFrameData` variable in another function?

Comment: I use it to play live streaming. It's usually around 20 times (equal to number of frames), but may reach up to 60 frame/second.

Comment: I don't change it anywhere, that's why I am getting confused

Comment: You could provide a [mcve], I just tried it and I do not see any problem. If we can not reproduce your problem it will be difficult for someone to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc I wanted, but it's a part of a big project. I try to separate it, and maybe in that way I get some clue.

Comment: I do not know if you have worked previously on a large project, but the main project is never modified, first you must create a small project oriented to your functionality, this must pass the testing process, and when you no longer have bugs you must integrate it into your project main and go through the testing phase again.

Comment: @eyllanesc You are right, it's the first time I am doing such kind of project alone. Now I will create it as a separate project and update you. Thanks!

Comment: @eyllanesc Sometimes of course there may still be trouble on integration, even if te subproject is correct by itself. In such cases, being able to minimize large code bases helps. Modern version control facilitates it a lot: just add a branch and start cutting.any large projects can be very quickly reduced to 10% of their code size, and only then you need to get careful about trimming right parts out. The build times also drop drastically so it’s all more tractable. But I agree that a small project to demonstrate new functionality helps a lot. A craint of it is called “unit tests” :)

Comment: @KubaOber 
Obviously the integration always brings problems but the unit tests help to minimize them, and then obviously version control helps. ;)

Comment: @KubaOber Apart the unit tests help if you are going to ask a question here since it is practically a [mcve], on the other hand it is good to do it if you have never used a class or functionality, so it gives a small but very significant experience.